# React-router-dom routing to a new page with props

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My question might seem stupid because I don't have enough background in React JS. 
I have this component:

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import CourseInfo from "./CourseInfo";
import OneCourse from "./OneCourse";

class CourseList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="row courses">
            {this.props.corses.map(course => (
              <NavLink key={course._id} to={`/courses/profile/${course._id}`}>
                <OneCourse course={course} />
              </NavLink>
            ))}
          </div>
          <Route
            exact
            path={`/courses/profile/:id`}
            render={({ match }) => (
              <CourseInfo
                index={match.params.id}
                course={
                  this.props.corses.filter(el => el._id === match.params.id)[0]
                }
              />
            )}
          />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I click on `OneCourse` component, it shows me the `CourseList` component in the same page with the component `CourseInfo` added in the bottom.

How can I send user to a new page containing only `CourseInfo`, knowing that I have parameters to send from this component to `CourseInfo`? 
I want to show `CourseInfo` component in a different page that doesn't contain the `CourseList`

Comment: You have got one unopened `</BrowserRouter >`!

Comment: sorry @PraveenKumarPurushothaman, I copied a snippet of my code, and I copied it wrong

Comment: You might need to use `<Link>` for routing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<NavLink>` is just fine. For the rest, you might use the `<Switch>` component:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
class CourseList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path={`/`} render={({ match }) => (
              <div className="row courses">
                {this.props.corses.map(course => (
              <NavLink key={course._id} to={`/courses/profile/${course._id}`}>
                <OneCourse course={course} />
              </NavLink>
            ))}
            </div>
            )}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path={`/courses/profile/:id`}
            render={({ match }) => (
              <CourseInfo
                index={match.params.id}
                course={
                  this.props.corses.filter(el => el._id === match.params.id)[0]
                }
              />
            )}
          />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Quoting from the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md):

> Switch is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every  that matches the location renders inclusively.

With complex routing the *render props* approach gets confusing. Moving the routing to a separate component is a better approach:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import CourseList from './CourseList';
import Course from './Course';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={CourseList} />
       <Route exact path="/courses/profile/:id" component={Course} />
       </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then your `CourseInfo` component looks like:

```
class CourseList extends Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

          <div className="row courses">
            {this.props.corses.map(course => (
              <NavLink key={course._id} to={`/courses/profile/${course._id}`}>
                <OneCourse course={course} />
              </NavLink>
            ))}
          </div>
      </div>
    );   
} }
```

The official [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) provides plenty examples.

Comment: thank you. Switch did the trick. I also deleted the `BrowserRouter` tag from `CourseList` because I'm already having it in `index.js` which is the higher parent component